# Prevent Regex from Overwriting Previous Statement

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have the following string:

```
a = "in the year 2010-01-01 there was a red dog and in the year 2011-01-01 there was a blue cat"
```

**My Problem:** In the above string, I want to replace every 2010 with 2011 and every 2011 with 2012.

I tried the following code:

```
b = gsub("2010", "2011", a)
b = gsub("2011", "2012", b)
```

But it overwrites my progress!

I did this with 3 mini statements:

```
b = gsub("2010", "temp", a)
b = gsub("2011", "2012", b)
b = gsub("temp", "2011", b)
```

But is there a quicker way to do this in a single line of code?

Comment: you can just swap the order of them! :-)

Comment: @mark : the first one is the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can simply replace 2011 to 2012 first, followed by 2010 to 2011, in that order:

```r
b <- gsub("2011", "2012", b, fixed=TRUE)
b <- gsub("2010", "2011", b, fixed=TRUE)
```

More generally, you could use a regex replacement with a callback function.

Comment: @ Tim: thank you so much for your answer! if you have time, can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77965657/returning-row-numbers-when-conditions-are-met

Answer (score 2):

```
stringr::str_replace_all(a, c("2011" = "2012", "2010" = "2011"))
```

Or with base R:

```
a |> gsub("2011", "2012", x = _) |> gsub("2010", "2011", x = _)
```